# Makefile subshell if condition

Tags: shell, make

So I have the following code:

```
.PHONY: test
test:
ifeq ($(grep -Fxq "substring" ./file && echo 1 || echo 0), 1)
    //do something
else
    //do other thing
endif
```

The idea is simply to do something if I find a substring inside a file, however my condition never works. I can run the subshell command independently and it works as expected returning 1 when then the substring is found. Now I know I can simply put a bash if expression in the make file but I would like to use the make files own condition.

Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `grep` function in the `make`. But you can call the external binary by using function `shell`:

```
.PHONY: test
test:
ifeq ($(shell grep -Fxq "substring" ./file.txt && echo 1 || echo 0), 1)
    echo Yes
else
    echo No
endif
```

Another thing you should keep in mind - the `make` does not use bash (or ksh, zsh, any-other-sh) to process recipes (or `shell` function). The shell interpreter is the most primitive one: `sh`. Or to be more specific, the `make` reads its own SHELL variable (which is usually /bin/sh).

Comment: You can override the SHELL variable with `SHELL := /bin/bash`, at least in `GNU Make`.